# Styling embed svg in svg (On Chrome)

Tags: reactjs, svg, embed, css-transforms

As I read, embedding an svg in another SVG leads to create another document and therefore complexify a lot the styling of those svg ...

Is there a way to use the css property `transform : rotate(90Deg)` easily on only 1 of the embbed svg ?

I'm trying to rotate the background only and not the front svg which needs to stay vertically ...

This example will help you a lot to understand what I'm trying :

https://codesandbox.io/s/example-rotate-svg-mucs3

## **Edit**

Its seems that it works on Firefox but not in Chrome ... Does anyone know a solution for this in Chrome ?

Chrome's overview:
[image]

Firefox *(and wanted)* overview:

[image]

Comment: I didn't "Invalidate" your answer because I didn't ever validated it ...
Why delete the image I had posted thought ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [submitted this problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1132583#c3). Its has been [merged here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231535)

As a work-around while waiting for this "bug" to be corrected. ( Should take some time as it's been reported since 2013... )

I've added a `transform` porperty with `rotate(90) translate(0, -600)` directly ON the `<g>` inside of the "background.svg".

The translate thing is here beacause the center used for rotating is by default [0,0]. It's clearly explained [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/)